# What is the status Of Rudra's alleged delusion by Krishna?

Tags: shiva, krishna, maya

There is a claim that Krishna has stated in the Mahabharata that he has illusioned Rudra and others:

http://www.vrindavana.net/academy/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/visnu-sahasra-nama-baladeva-I.pdf

page 5 has the Sanskrit version and page 49 Hindi that can be translated as

> "The patriarchs, rudra and others are created by Me, though they do not know that are created by Me, because they are deluded by My illusory energy."

Assuming that this citation is citing something from the Mahabharata as it claims -

Does any scripture say if Rudra and others ever got out of this delusion?  If there is no such citation - does that mean these Gods would be deluded till eternity?

And is this consistent with Arjuna's prayer to Siva FROM THE SAME MAHABHARATA?

http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03039.htm

> Vaisampayana continued, "Phalguna then beheld him--Mahadeva--that god of blazing splendour-that wielder of the Pinaka-that one who had his abode on the mountains (of Kailasa)--accompanied by Uma. Bending down on his knee and bowing with his head, that conqueror of hostile cities-the son of Pritha-worshipped Hara and inclined him to grace. And Arjuna said, 'O Kapardin, O chief of all gods, O destroyer of the eyes of Bhaga, O god of gods, O Mahadeva, O thou of blue throat, O thou of matted locks, I know thee as the Cause of all causes. O thou of three eyes, O lord of all! Thou art the refuge of all the gods! This universe hath sprung from thee. Thou art incapable of being vanquished by the three worlds of the celestials, the Asuras, and men. Thou art Siva in the form of Vishnu, and Vishnu in the form of Siva. Thou destroyedest of old the great sacrifice of Daksha. O Hari, O Rudra, I bow to thee. Thou hast an eye on thy forehead. O Sarva, O thou that rainest objects of desire, O bearer of the trident, O wielder of the Pinaka, O Surya, O thou of pure body, O Creator of all, I bow to thee. O lord of all created things, I worship thee to obtain thy grace. Thou art the lord of the Ganas, the source of universal blessing, the Cause of the causes of the universe. Thou art beyond the foremost of male beings, thou art the highest, thou art the subtlest, O Hara! O illustrious Sankara, it behoveth thee to pardon my fault. It was even to obtain a sight of thyself that I came to this great mountain, which is dear to thee and which is the excellent abode of ascetics. Thou art worshipped of all

Comment: Now you understand where is the delusion, Sir:)

Comment: There are so many passages inconsistent with the one like [this](http://mahabharata-resources.org/harivamsa/vishnuparva/hv_2_072.html) but Rudra doesn't always translate to Shiva.

Comment: These debates mean nothing to me. As SrimRamakrishna said: Who can say any final word about God? Call Him sincerely and Henwill make you understand. Sir, these debates mean nothing.